# MySQL is corrupted and not able to start mysql even after innodb_force_recovery=6

Tags: mysql

Here are Error logs from MySQL:

```
2023-09-25T23:38:12.380772Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.418767Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6192  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.421467Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6193  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.422620Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6194  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.423685Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6195  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.424557Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6196  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.425909Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6197  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:14.426901Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 6198  user: 'root'.
2023-09-25T23:38:16.030825Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-09-25T23:38:59.608005Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2023-09-25T23:38:59.613534Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 3568
2023-09-25T23:38:59.715343Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=100663296. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2023-09-25T23:38:59.761951Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-25T23:39:01.861228Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.849492Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.850185Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.954434Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-09-25T23:39:11.955369Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2023-09-26T05:50:57.065725Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2023-09-26T05:50:57.070263Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 3988
2023-09-26T05:50:57.150635Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=100663296. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2023-09-26T05:50:57.193995Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-26T05:50:59.560045Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-09-26T05:51:02.608838Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2023-09-26T05:51:02.614958Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2023-09-26T05:51:02.651234Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:81:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 4408
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-09-26T05:51:02Z UTC - mysqld got exception 0x16 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1b01b26c880
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7c385fa68    mysqld.exe!?my_print_stacktrace@@YAXPEBEK@Z()
7ff7c29e9411    mysqld.exe!?print_fatal_signal@@YAXH@Z()
7ff7c29e9153    mysqld.exe!?my_server_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7c3843a7a    mysqld.exe!?my_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7c3a9c7f9    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7c3976c20    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3975dd2    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c39752b4    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3974a9c    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3951b52    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c3955644    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c395f07e    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7c395f4e5    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ffa58166b4c    ucrtbase.dll!_recalloc()
7ffa59b94ed0    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffa5abfe40b    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I'm unable to start MySQL even after adding innodb_force_recovery=1 to 6. Please give any suggestions, everything is appreciated. I'm stuck with this issue for days now. If you need anything else, please let me know.

I have my database ibd files only, under data folder, please let me know if there is a way to recover them directly from idb files, although I tried by creating a new mysql instance, then creating database and tables and then tried to import the files into it, it failed though.

Comment: I don't know any way to recover from that error. If I were in this situation, I would restore the database from the most recent backup. Alternatively, if I had a replica, I would quickly promote the replica to be the new source.

Comment: Backup that I have is 3 months old, which is not suitable.

Comment: Then I assume the data wasn't important to you?

Comment: We started development of the application 6 months back and it was on production, customers are using the app, but we did not start taking backup. That's bad on our side.

Comment: I see. What have you learned from this experience?